# Can UIBarButtonItems in a Toolbar have a Background Image in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to use the following code to set a custom background image for a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolbar` on iOS7.

```
    NSString *imageName = selected ? @"background_view_baritem_selected" : @"background_view_baritem_normal";
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIImage *resizableBackgroundImage = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
[self setBackgroundImage:resizableBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In the debugger, using QuickLook, I can verify that `resizableBackgroundImage` is what I would expect it to be (a rounded blue rectangle when selected and a rounded gray rectangle normally).  However, no background image appears.  This code works as expected on iOS6 (the background image is displayed).  Is iOS7 imposing its will and not displaying a background in this case or is their something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm doing the exact sequence of calls in my code, my custom images are showing up just fine in iOS 7 (I'm in my code now and just double checked it).  I also tried it with and without a custom image for the navbar, and it worked fine either way.

Comment: If you're desperate, you could try and set the `customView` property to an `UIImageView` containing the image. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: @HaIR This seems to work on a NavigationBar, but not on a Toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, I was able to resolve it only by using custom view.
E.g if you have some outlet for UIBarButtonItem

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet  UIBarButtonItem *item;
```

..... in you code you can do something like this:

```
UIImage *configImage = /* initialize necessary image */;
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, item.width, 32)];
[btn setBackgroundImage:configImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:item.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[btn addTarget:item.target action:item.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

item.customView = btn;
```

Comment: I didn't use an IBOutlet myself (no XIB for my view), but this works on iOS 7 for me; I had tried many other solutions that all failed. Thank you.